# putting numpy ndarray data into pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pandas

I want to put the following data into pandas for further analysis.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

data = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, np.nan, 1], [np.nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                 [[2, np.nan, 2, 2, 2], [2, np.nan, 2, 2, 2]],
                 [[3, 3, 3, np.nan, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, np.nan]]])

pnda = pd.Series(data)

print pnda
```

But the following error occurs:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

What is the good way of doing it? My further analysis is to filling the np.nan values by interpolation with cubic or polynomial method and output the result as numpy array.

Comment: Use a DataFrame for multidimentional data, not a Series.

Comment: @Ffisegydd it seems that `DataFrame` only accepts 2-D arrays...

Comment: @neha do you really need to pass a 3-D array to Pandas?

Comment: Ah yes sorry. I think DataFrames are the way to go rather than Series (which is typically a 1D "array" I think) but I don't know how to handle ND arrays greater than N.

Comment: @SaulloCastro yes, because in pandas there is builtin function for interpolating the missing data

Comment: @neha perhaps you can reshape this to a 2-D array and perform the interpolation in the way you want

Comment: @SaulloCastro But in my real world problem, my data shape is 15*6200*6200 which is ofcourse not possible to show in the question

Comment: @neha how do you want the interpolation, can you provide an example of the output?

Comment: the np.nan should be filled by all the available elements in other arrays corresponding to the position of np.nan

Comment: The 2d are filled as http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: @Saullo Castro they are to be interpolated by column wise (i.e., 1,2,3 values)

Comment: Why not use a `Panel`? They accept 3D arrays just fine. Hell, that's where `pan` in `pandas` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments you can achieve what you want if you reshape `data`, interpolate using the `DataFrame.interpolate()` method and then return the array to its original value. It works for **pandas 0.13.1**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(2, -1))
df.interpolate(axis=1).values.reshape(data.shape)
#array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
#
#       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],
#
#       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a panel:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[[1, 1, 1, np.nan, 1], [np.nan, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                 [[2, np.nan, 2, 2, 2], [2, np.nan, 2, 2, 2]],
                 [[3, 3, 3, np.nan, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, np.nan]]])

x = pd.Panel(data)
x

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 5 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 2
Major_axis axis: 0 to 1
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 4
```

And...

```
print(x.loc[0])
    0  1  2   3  4
0   1  1  1 NaN  1
1 NaN  1  1   1  1
```

Comment: Not that `interpolate` isn't implemented on Panels iirc, which was the OP's original need. You'll probably need to iterate over the items of the panel.

Comment: @TomAugspurger or maybe a nested `apply` 0_o